# (Zend) Soap Server doesn't return results

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I've been trying to setup a Soap Server using Zend_Soap_Server, but I can't seem to make it work.
I have tried several different environments: nginx and apache on a linux vm, apache on windows, php 5.3 and php 5.4, all yield the same results.

Using Zend_Soap_Autodiscover it correctly generates a wsdl. When I feed that wsdl to SoapClient and invoke a method on it, it doesn't return a response. It seems like php halts after SoapServer::handle() is called.

This is the server part:

```
ini_set('soap.enable_wsdl_cache', 0);

require_once 'Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover.php';
require_once 'Zend/Soap/Server.php';

if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    handleWsdl();
} else {
    handleSoap();
}

function handleWsdl() {
    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->addFunction('pi');
    $autodiscover->handle();
}

function handleSoap() {
    $soap = new Zend_Soap_Server('http://localhost/experiments/soap/server.php?wsdl');
    $soap->setWsdlCache(false);
    $soap->addFunction('pi');
    $soap->handle();
}
```

And this is the client:

```
ini_set('soap.enable_wsdl_cache', 0);

$wsdl = 'http://localhost/experiments/soap/server.php?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

$result = $client->pi();
var_dump($result);
```

The `$result` is `NULL`.

I'm running out of ideas and hope someone can help me solve this mystery.

BTW: I have also tried SoapUI to consume the webservice, but the results are the same.

Comment: ok, this might be silly, but do you have actual function named "pi" on the server side?

Comment: php.net/pi, it's a built-in function :)

Comment: right :)
well why not wrap "pi()" up in "pi2()" or something similar and add some basic alert/echo/something in front, then you can at least check on server side that your code is being called from client... (ie you can verify that request gets to right place on server).
also, Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover uses PHP docblocks to determine data types to return via soap, perhaps pi() isn't all that well described?
perhaps return value of "pi()" should also be wrapped in some soap envelope, or presented as some stdclass or something...
just thinking out loud...

Comment: I have already tried that. Using built-ins, using my own functions, uses classes.. documented and not documented. Nothing seems to work. This has taken too much time already.. so I switched to a json rpc server. It took me all of two minutes to get it functional. So I'm closing the question now. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Hi @DennisHaarbrink I have the same problem in my Soap Server and I don't know where is the problem. Have you found some solution to your issue?

Comment: @Michelangelo, as you can see in my comment I stopped using SoapServer and switched to a json rpc server. Is still working great for me!

Comment: Hi @DennisHaarbrink I have tried to fix the problem using the below solution. Let me know if it works!

Comment: @Michelangelo, I am not working with Zend Framework anymore, so I can't test your solution. Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I have found the problem. Please check and report if it is correct with your vote.
I have changed the way to call the Soap using the options and not the main uri parameter, in this way:

```
try{
        // initialize SOAP client
        $options = array(
                'location'  => 'http://localhost/experiments/soap/server.php',
                'uri'       => 'http://localhost/experiments/soap/server.php'
        );

        $client = new Zend_Soap_Client(null, $options);
        $result = $client->pi();
        Zend_Debug::dump($result);

    }catch(SoapFault $e){
        Zend_Debug::dump($e);
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

If you call the WSDL the client cannot call the "pi()" method. Try it and let me know.

Regards